# Does adding another variable length column to a table with variable length rows further impact performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that changing a table with fixed width rows to have variable width rows (by changing a CHAR column to a VARCHAR) has performance implications.

However my question is, given a preexisting table with variable width rows (due to many VARCHAR columns), and thus with that performance penalty already paid, would adding another variable length column further impact performance?

My hunch is that it wouldn't, the biggest performance penalty would be switching from fixed width rows to variable width rows and that adding another variable width column would have a negligible impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. It is true that variable width character columns are *slightly* slower then fixed width character columns. But the "penalty" (or performance cost) is cummulative and per column. So, every column you add to your query in general (fixed width or otherwise) is going to impact performance (as you query more data, it takes longer to fetch all of the data).

Answer (score 1):

Each Variable length column you add to the table, makes it worse to retrieve the data.
Another consideration would also be - if the variable length columns are part of the Query (filter/Where clause) and if you are going to be using those in indexes. Variable Length fields in the index will also add to the index overhead. For details, you will need to look at the documentation of the particular database you are using. e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Extracting a data row into the component fields will take a few extra cycles.

That, however, will be more than offset by the almost certain reduction in row size — meaning more rows per data page and thus faster lookups across the board.

Answer (score 0):

It will make a *tiny* (measured in microseconds)  difference to data retrieval performance, BUT the human performance impact of using the wrong datatype just to squeeze every last drop out of the database could be large and therefore costly.

Use the datatype most appropriate for the attribute you're persisting in the database.
Don't be driven by "performance", be driven by the usual guidelines for software development, like readability, maintainability, use ability, etc.

Use the wrong datatype and your code will be more complex (possibly losing more performance gain than you gained), and you'll regretted ever doing it. And I doubt you would ever notice those gains anyway.

Only do such things when you have proof that there's a problem, and the problem is large enough to matter. Doing what you're proposing is called "premature optimization", and is probably the worst  design strategy there is.